# Running a Web Page On More Than One Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a web page that reads an input file and outputs a dashboard.  Every month there will be a new input file (stored in its own sub directory with some other files) and I want to be able to archive the old files and display them in a drop down menu as options to display.  I can read the home directory and get a list of all the directories but I can't figure out how to run the web page using the chosen directory as an argument.

Comment: Response.Redirect("~/" + ddl.SelectedItem.Text + "/Page.aspx");

Comment: @HanletEscaño: This looks encouraging.  How do I read ddl.Selecteditem.Text in Page.aspx?

Comment: I might not be understanding your question I guess. Why do you need to know the value of ddl.SelectedItem.Text in the target page. What I get from your question is that you have a list of folders on a dropdownlist and then when the user clicks on an item, you want to show certain page from the selected folder right?

Comment: I have one web page.  It processes a couple of files and displays a dashboard.  I would like to be able to run this page on files in different directories.

Comment: @Kevin please can you put some code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting the drop down list in the web code so that it is displayed on page load and the html for the dashboard is hidden.  When  selection is made the table is populated and made visible.  It just means that there is always a drop down list at the top of my tables but I have decided that this is a good thing.